# what is the C++ equivalent for this assembly code

Tags: c++, assembly, rdtsc

I'm trying to figure out how to read this assembly code in C++.

This is the code:

```cpp
unsigned __int64 high_perf_time;
unsigned __int64 *dest = &high_perf_time;
__asm 
{
    _emit 0xf        // these two bytes form the 'rdtsc' asm instruction,
    _emit 0x31       //  available on Pentium I and later.
    mov esi, dest
    mov [esi  ], eax    // lower 32 bits of tsc
    mov [esi+4], edx    // upper 32 bits of tsc
}
__int64 time_s     = (__int64)(high_perf_time / frequency);  // unsigned->sign conversion should be safe here
__int64 time_fract = (__int64)(high_perf_time % frequency);  // unsigned->sign conversion should be safe here
```

I know `0xf 0x31` is `rdtsc eax, edx`, but what is `mov esi,dest`? How can I write that in C++?

Comment: The `move esi, dest` instruction moves the contents of the `destination` location in the `esi` register.  An equivalent is an assignment statement.

Comment: You can't write to a register in C++. Or read from one. You need all those assembly instructions since MSVC has no syntax for specifying the output operands of an inline piece of assembly code.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: WIth MSVC, you'd just use `QueryPerformanceCounter()` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` and not use inline assembly code at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt It depends on what OP wants to actually do. But they didn't say, that's why this is not a good question. I read it as asking how to store `edx:eax` in a variable without using assembly. I see your answer is what OP wanted.

Comment: @MargaretBloomL Yes, it was necessary to abstract the task performed by those lines as not "copy edx and eax into a variable" but "store the rdtsc results into a variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ code is

```
#include <intrin.h>
unsigned __int64 high_perf_time = __rdtsc();
```

Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/rdtsc

But you probably want `QueryPerformanceCounter()` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` instead, else you will have a race condition if your thread is scheduled on a different processor core between successive `__rdtsc()` calls.

Comment: Thank you yes i read it in first core work great !

Comment: `__rdtscp` also gives you the core ID from the same instruction the TSC reading came from.  If it was a different core you could just discard that measurement if it's for a short microbenchmark, since it had context-switch overhead.  (Most modern CPUs in practice do have the TSC synced across cores, although it's not guaranteed, especially for multi-socket system.),  @maor03 .

Comment: BTW, microbenchmarking is hard; just using `rdtscp` is not enough to reliably benchmark very short intervals; clock frequency varies, but TSC frequency doesn't, among other effects.   See also  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to **understand** what these three instructions do:

The following three instructions:

```
    mov esi, dest
    mov [esi  ], eax    // lower 32 bits of tsc
    mov [esi+4], edx    // upper 32 bits of tsc
```

... are the equivalent of the following C++ code:

```
    uint32_t * esi = (uint32_t *)dest;
    esi[0] = eax;
    esi[1] = edx;
```

And because the x86 CPUs are "little-endian", this is equal to:

```
    *dest = (((__int64_t)edx)<<32) + (uint32_t)eax;
```

... however, because you **cannot** access the `eax` and `edx` registers directly using C++, this operation **must** be done in assembly code.

Comment: "you cannot access the eax and edx registers directly using C++" -- True.  "this operation must be done in assembly code" -- False.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was only referring to the last 3 lines of assembly code because the OP only asked about those lines.